# Reindexing Solr Data with different field type

Tags: solr, schema, solrcloud, reindex

I am facing an issue while reindexing Solr data.

I have indexed some documents specifying a wrong field type on the managed-schema file.
Now, instead of the wrong field definition, I would like to use:

```
<field name="documentDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

To do this I have:

- deleted all the previous wrong indexed documents;
- updated the managed-schema
- reloaded the core

After these steps I tried to reindex documents, but this fails; looking at logs:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception writing document id 2ecde3eb2b5964b2c44362f752f7b90d to the index; possible analysis error: cannot change DocValues type from NUMERIC to SORTED_SET for field "documentDate".
```

How is this possible? I have removed all the documents storing the field documentDate.. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you optimized your index after deleting documents? Deleted documents aren't expunged before after the index is rewritten to disk

Comment: @MatsLindh, yes I deleted all those documents with "<delete><query>type:documentType</query></delete>" from documents section, and then optimized the core from core admin.. Is there another way to purge this unwanted field? (I cannot recreate the core, I have to keep other documents in the core )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe try to delete the data folder in your core.
You can add new fields to your schema without delete the data folder, but when you modify a field (this is my experience) then I have to delete the data folder and build a new fresh index

Comment: In the end I was not able to reindex existing fields with correct type. So, instead of creating a new core I decided to delete existing wrong documents and to re-index all these documents with a different field type and different field names. In this way existing and correct data is not touched. I will accept your answer because the other possible solution ( without changing fields name) was to build a new fresh index.